# To which device is the output of a Gitlab CI pipeline written?

Tags: terminal, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, tty

I have the following statement in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
( docker-compose up  & ) | ( tee /dev/tty & ) | grep -m 1 "Compiled successfully"
```

It shall show the output of `docker-compose up` in the web terminal and wait for a certain string to indicate that the containers are ready.

But `/dev/tty` fails with the error: `tee: /dev/tty: No such device or address`

The output of `tty` is `not a tty`. How do I find out where the output is actually written to? The Gitlab runner runs on Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this using:

```
- docker-compose up -d
- docker-compose logs -f &
```

This will keep outputting the logs of `docker-compose` in the foreground.

Notice this will generate mixed output of both your containers as well as any following commands your `.gitlab-ci.yml` contains.